# What files need to go into secure directory?

Tags: php, ssl

If I call a single PHP file that in turn uses GET's and POST's to build the HTML page as well as process other data and store it in SESSION, do I need to mirror the entire site into an HTTPS capable directory or does only the page being called need to be in the directory?

So for example my computer sends my name via POST to the server and specifically Index.php.

If the address of Index.php is  is the data secure going to the server?
Is the data returning, most specifically the SESSION data, also secure?

Also I apologize if this quest has been answered a hundred times, for some reason I could not think of the proper search terms to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I need to mirror the entire site into an HTTPS capable directory or does only the page being called need to be in the directory?

No. Webserver can be set up so it watches to the same directory for both http and https

> If the address of Index.php is is the data secure going to the server?

If it is a **https** protocol specified in the url - then all the traffic (request from client to server and response from server to client) between client and serever is crypted.

> Is the data returning, most specifically the SESSION data, also secure?

Session data is never sent to client. It is stored on the server.

Comment: Alright so I should be good just putting the index.php into the secure directory and calling it thru a secure connection.

Comment: @Magic Lasso: if `index.php` is the only file you need to serve using https - then yes.